# Multiple Navigation Links Not Working in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, navigationview

Im a beginner in swift and I am using navigation view and navigation links to allow the user to move between different pages.
My app has a homeView and a sliding menu view. Homeview is a parent to MenuView, MenuView opens up when the user clicks a button. Now in menu view I want to redirect the user to different pages based on what the click, this is my menu view:

struct MenuView: View {

```
@EnvironmentObject var sessionService: SessionServiceImpl

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        
        NavigationLink(destination: EditProfileView(), label: {
        
            VStack {
        Text("Hi \(sessionService.userDetails?.firstName ?? "N/A")")
            .foregroundColor(.white)

        
        Text("\(sessionService.userDetails?.lastName ?? "N/A")")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .padding(.top, 100)
        })

                       
        NavigationLink(destination: RideHistoryView(), label: {
        HStack {
              Image(systemName: "clock")
                  .foregroundColor(.white)
                  .imageScale(.large)
              Text("Ride History")
                  .foregroundColor(.white)
                  .font(.headline)
          }        .padding(.top, 30)
        })
      
       
        NavigationLink(destination: HelpView(), label: {
        HStack {
              Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                  .foregroundColor(.white)
                  .imageScale(.large)
              Text("Help")
                  .foregroundColor(.white)
                  .font(.headline)
          }
        })
              .padding(.top, 30)
        
          HStack {
              Button {
                  sessionService.logout()
              } label: {
                  Image(systemName: "rectangle.portrait.and.arrow.right")
                      .foregroundColor(.white)
                      .imageScale(.large)
                  Text("Sign Out")
                      .foregroundColor(.white)
                      .font(.headline)
              }
          }
              .padding(.top, 30)
        
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .background(.blue)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

For some reason, only the help button works when I simulate it. Yet I used the same principles for all the other buttons. Would anybody know why it is not working.

For reference this is my HomeView:

```
//
//  HomeView.swift
//  MyEBike
//
//  Created by Marina Vlachandreas on 2022-01-22.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showMenu = false
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionService: SessionServiceImpl
    
    var body: some View {
        
    let drag = DragGesture()
        .onEnded {
            if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showMenu = false
                }
            }
        }

        return NavigationView {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack (alignment: .leading) {
                HomeView(showMenu: self.$showMenu)
                    .environmentObject(self.sessionService)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height:
                    geometry.size.height)
                    .offset(x: self.showMenu ? geometry.size.width/2 : 0)
                    .disabled(self.showMenu ? true : false)
 
            
            if (self.showMenu) {
                MenuView()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/2)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                    .environmentObject(self.sessionService)
                    }
                }
            .gesture(drag)
            
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(leading: (
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showMenu.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        ))
    }
}


struct HomeView: View {
    
    @Binding var showMenu: Bool
    
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionService: SessionServiceImpl
    
    let skyBlue = Color(red: 0.4627, green: 0.8392, blue: 1.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            skyBlue.ignoresSafeArea()
           }
            
    }
}


struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
        ContentView()
                .environmentObject(SessionServiceImpl())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with my spacer() when I remove it everything works but it’s not formatted well

Answer (score 1):

Use this code with a key for each page you need in identifier

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Name")
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
  
let parentVC = presentingViewController
    dismiss(animated: true) {
      parentVC!.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
```